# Unable to add Visual Studio Code app's icon to macOS Dock

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, dock, visual-studio-code

I had [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) app's icon in my Mac's Dock before, but I can't put it there again.

I tried dragging and dropping the app bundle from the `/Applications` folder, but the icon doesn't **land** in the Dock. Have I accidentally banned **Visual Studio Code.app** from the macOS Dock?

If yes, how can I revoke the ban? I can add icons for other apps just fine. Even when I have **Visual Studio Code.app** running, the app's icon doesn't appear in the Dock.

How do I resolve the issue and get the app icon to show in the Dock?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try restring the Dock by running `killall Dock` in the Terminal.

Comment: @NimeshNeema that worked :D Plz make it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 138, accepted):

> Have I accidentally banned Visual Studio Code.app from the macOS Dock?

No.

> How do I resolve the issue and get the app icon to show in the Dock?

You can try resolving the issue by killing the Dock process and re-launching it afresh. To do that, launch Terminal.app and execute the following command-line:

`killall Dock`

The command-line is case sensitive. Once executed, the Dock would momentarily disappear and then reappear.  Now you should be able to add the **Visual Studio Code.app** icon normally by dragging in the app bundle. You should also be able to see the icon normally when the app is running.

Comment: Yes, basic troubleshooting steps are usually: 1. Killall the dock 2. Killall the Finder 3. Reboot

Comment: I did reboot my Mac and it didn't work. Killing the dock as described worked. That is weird. Thank you.

Comment: That... actually worked. I don't know why. Thank you!

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"